# quick question about ampleness of the following line bundle.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

I have a quick question concerning the ampleness of the following line bundle, it came up in an article I've been trying to read.

Suppose that $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ is a morphism of complex projective varieties. Suppose that $L$ is a very ample line bundle on $X$, and $M$ is a very ample line bundle on $Y$. Why is it true that $\pi^{*}(L^{d}) \otimes M$ an ample line bundle on $Y$ for some large value of $d$?

Note that I am not saying that  $\pi^{*}(L) \otimes M^{d}$ is ample for large $d$, but that  $\pi^{*}(L^{d}) \otimes M$ is ample. I can verify the former case.

Thank you!

Comment: $M$ is ample, $\pi^*L$ is nef, so..

Comment: @ChenJiang Hi, I must not be aware of this result.. Can you please provide a reference? Thank you!

Comment: the easiest way to see this is Hartshorne Exercise II.7.5. Actually d=1 is enough.